# How is accessing items in dictionary using ["id"] different from using .id?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain the difference between `blog_post.id` and `blog_post["id"]`?

```
@app.route("/post/<int:index>")
def show_post(index):
    requested_post = None
    for blog_post in post_objects:
        if blog_post.id == index:
            requested_post = blog_post
    return render_template("post.html", post=requested_post)

[{"id":1,
"body":"Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery. Bunya nuts black-eyed pea prairie turnip leek lentil turnip greens parsnip. Sea lettuce lettuce water chestnut eggplant winter purslane fennel azuki bean earthnut pea sierra leone bologi leek soko chicory celtuce parsley jícama salsify.",
"title":"The Life of Cactus",
"subtitle":"Who knew that cacti lived such interesting lives."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has two concepts here. *attributes* and *items*. Attributes are accessed via dots `object.attribute`, items with square brackets and depending on the data type by integers (lists) or hashable items for example strings.
`block_post['id']`

Python dicts are of the latter category. You can use strings, beside others, to access the *item*.

Some customized dict (-like) classes allow to mix both styles, they are more ambiguous and you might not be sure if an attribute points to a stored item or attribute, which might be a function or fixed value not set by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you use `["id"]` on dictionaries and `.id` on objects that declares `id` as a field:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

a = A(1)
print(a.id)     # 1
print(a["id"])  # Won't work
```

```
a = {'id': 1, 'name': 'John Doe'}
print(a.id)     # Won't work
print(a["id"])  # 1
```

The long answer: Python implements the Object-Oriented Programming. Any class that declares a `__getitem__` method can be called with `[...]`. Therefore, dictionaries also declare this method.

```
class B:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(f'Key: {key}')

b = B()
b['abc']    # Outputs `Key: abc`
```

And any class that declares a `id` attribute or declares a `__getattr__` method can be called with `id`:

```py
class C:
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print(f'Key: {key}')

c = C()
c.id    # Outputs `Key: id`

class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 'Key: 1'
    
d = D()
print(d.id)  # Outputs `Key: 1`

class E:
    @property
    def id(self):
        return 'Key: 1'
    
e = E()
print(e.id)  # Outputs `Key: 1`
```

Comment: The bracketed style is not limited to dictionaries. It could be any object that implements \_\_getitem__

Comment: @CtrlZ Have you read the last part of my answer?

Comment: I read your answer before you edited it

Comment: @CtrlZ So delete your comment. It's no longer relevant.

Comment: @KellyBundy I didn't say *all* objects, but since you're that pedantic, I've updated my answer.

Comment: You might also want to elaborate on the dot notation and mention that it can apply to any object that implements \_\_getattr__

Comment: @CtrlZ Now that's an useful improvement! Will do.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between both is to use `blog_post.id` when referring to an attribute or property of the class and use `blog_post["id"]` when you're using a dictionary.

Your JSON contains a list of `post_objects`, where each `blog_post` is a dictionary. That's why you should refer to the `id` of the `bolg_post` by using the dictionary format which is `bolg_post["id"]`.

Here's the version of your code which uses bracket notation to parse the JSON:

```
@app.route("/post/<int:index>")
def show_post(index):
    requested_post = None
    for blog_post in post_objects:
        if blog_post["id"] == index:
            requested_post = blog_post
    return render_template("post.html", post=requested_post)
```

You can use `blog_post.id`, wherever you have defined a class to map the JSON data to class, and subsequently use `dot(.)` notation to access that specific attribute of an instance.

To map JSON to class, you can use `dataclass`, here's the sample code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class BlogPost:
    id: int
    body: str
    title: str
    subtitle: str

# list of blog posts
post_objects = [
    {"id": 1, "body": "Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery...",
     "title": "The Life of Cactus", "subtitle": "Who knew that cacti lived such interesting lives."}
]

# Map JSON to dataclass
post_objects = [BlogPost(**post) for post in post_objects]

# here's your code using dot(.) notation
@app.route("/post/<int:index>")
def show_post(index):
    requested_post = None
    for blog_post in post_objects:
        if blog_post.id == index:
            requested_post = blog_post
    return render_template("post.html", post=requested_post)
```